# Exception handler doesn't catch exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exception

I have two projects in one solution. The 1st it's library project and the second it's Asp.Net WebApi project. Both using .Net Framework 4.6.1.
I want to make some class that will handling exceptions globally. I found nice solution using ExceptionHandler, however it doesn't work as I expected. I was following this article https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling.
Here is my class where I handle exceptions.

```
public class GlobalExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler
{
    public override void HandleCore(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        context.Result = new TextPlainErrorResult
        {
            Request = context.ExceptionContext.Request,
            Content = context.Exception.Message
        };
    }

    private class TextPlainErrorResult : IHttpActionResult
    {
        public HttpRequestMessage Request { get; set; }

        public string Content { get; set; }

        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response =
                             new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            response.Content = new StringContent(Content);
            response.RequestMessage = Request;
            return Task.FromResult(response);
        }
    }
}
```

For instance I have this code in my library project.

```
 public class ThrowSomething
{
   public void ThrowSomeException()
   {
      throw new Exception("Custom exception");
   }
}
```

And in my controller in Asp.Net I have

```
public IHttpActionResult SomeAction()
    {
        var throwSomething = new ThrowSomething();
        throwSomething.ThrowSomeException();
        return Ok();
    }
```

I would like to catch the exception in my GlobalExceptionHandler class and return some result to the Api. Currently the GlobalExceptionHandler is not handling the exceptions.

I also have `config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new GlobalExceptionHandler());` in Register method in WebApiConfig.

Comment: Doesn't work as expected...  What is the current behaviour?  Your library project is referenced under your webapi project?  Is you GlobalExceptionHandler is in the WebApi project (the main one)?

Comment: How about you try creating a `BaseController` in which you override OnActionExecuted method that will then allow you to check whether the results of the action execution threw an `Exception`, whether the `Exception` was handled and the `Type` of exception thrown.

Comment: I don't have any problem with throwing exceptions. As I said the ExceptionHandler just don't handle the exceptions. Even if I throw an exception directly in the controller the handler will not catch it.

Comment: Check the `Boolean` return value of the `ShouldHandle` method; it must be `True` in order to trigger the `HandleCore` method.

Comment: huh, Thanks @pfx you are right. After changing the code in ShouldHandle to return true it works fine.